# flutter run does failed on mac os for plugin url_launcher

Tags: flutter

flutter run does not work for below plugin , my mac os version is 10.15.4 (19E287)

url_launcher: ^5.0.2

error message is as below shown, my assumption is due to macOS update, it used to work!
macOS downgrade is not possible for me, any suggestion or hints for this problem?

Thanks in adance!

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':url_launcher:compileDebugAidl'.

  > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':url_launcher:debugCompileClasspath'.
  >   Could not resolve project :url_launcher_macos.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :url_launcher
  >   Unable to find a matching configuration of project :url_launcher_macos:
  >         - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46905 looks like the issue has been fixed. Please check the workaround and try.

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me**

> NOTE:- CLOSE THE FLUTTER PROJECT

1. Go to Flutter sdk path
2. Enable the view hidden files in Mac by using CTRL + SHIFT + .
3. Go to .pub-cache
4. Go to hosted
5. Go to pub.dartlang.org
6. delete this folder url_launcher_macos
7. Open the project and run app