# Build error in Gradle/Flutter: 'Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration'?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, classpath

Trying to build the application, the compiler spits out this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app_settings'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app_settings:classpath'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.70.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.70/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.70.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app_settings
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.61.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.61/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.61.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app_settings > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1
         project :app_settings > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.6.1
         project :app_settings > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.6.1
         project :app_settings > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.6.1
         project :app_settings > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:3.6.1
         project :app_settings > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.6.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.6.1
         project :app_settings > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.6.1 > com.android.tools:common:26.6.1
         project :app_settings > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.6.1 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.6.1
         project :app_settings > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.6.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:26.6.1
         project :app_settings > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.6.1 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.6.1 > com.android.tools:repository:26.6.1
         project :app_settings > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.6.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.6.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.6.1
   > Could not find org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/7.0/asm-7.0.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app_settings > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1
         project :app_settings > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.6.1
   > Could not find org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:7.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/7.0/asm-analysis-7.0.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app_settings > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1
   > Could not find org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/7.0/asm-commons-7.0.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app_settings > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1
         project :app_settings > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.6.1
   > Could not find org.ow2.asm:asm-util:7.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/7.0/asm-util-7.0.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app_settings >....
```

Full output at :https://pastebin.com/Vj67AWAH

I've tried removing the app_settins plugin, but it just fails on another plugin, so I think is a general problem, not a plugin-specific one.

I tried to re-install AndroidStudio, in different version, just like the jdk and the flutter sdk

I'm just can't wrap my head around it

HELP!

---

EDIT

Here's the build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: update your gradle version and open Android module and select Invalidate Caches/Restart from File section . it maybe helps

Comment: Nope, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: what repositories do you have in your build.gradle file? do you have google() and jcenter()?

Comment: There are jcenter() and google(), in the main build.gradle at least.
Is that the one you were asking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a fluke, but searching online I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62643069/13159267)!

Kinda following it, I deleted all the cached plugins in
`user_folder>/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/`
and then run flutter pub get in the project.

Now it works.

If anyone knows why/how this works, please explain it, thx!